# How to keep track of pending builds in Jenkins?

Tags: java, api, jenkins

I need to find what build id's were assigned to a pending build in Jenkins.

I saw that Build History keeps track of them and displays them to the user but I didn't find them displayed in an api form (xml in my case) at this link

```
http://localhost:8080/job/JobName/api/xml
```

How can I get this information from Jenkins ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the queue API:

```
JENKINS_URL/queue/api/xml
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more of an explanation to your answer? It might help OP or future users more.

Comment: My problem occurs if I have more than one pending build. I checked the link and it seems it displays only the last pending build...

Answer (score 0):

You can get a detailed description of Jenkins job API passing a `/api` to the end of the job url.

Use `JENKINS_URL/job/<your-job>/api` . At the and of the provided help page, you can find this info:

if you start a job programmatically by an API request...

> ... successful queueing will result in 201 status code with **Location HTTP header pointing the URL of the item in the queue**. By polling the api/xml sub-URL of the queue item, you can track the status of the queued task.